# How to return a subscription result from one method to another in angular 7?

Tags: angular, async-await, es6-promise

I have a method to upload a file

```
 uploadFiles(event, type) {
            var files = event.srcElement.files;
            for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i]['name']);
            }

            formData.append('formFlags', type);
            return await this.uploadService.upload(formData).subscribe(response => {
               //return response
            });
```

the above upload function is called from another function like

```
uploadMarketingAgreement(event) {
    this.uploadFiles(event, "profilepic");
   //how to get result of the above method in a varaible
}
```

how can i return the result of first (asynchronous) function to the second function?

Comment: Push the result into a behavior subject on a service, then any other component that needs the data can subscribe to the service.

Answer (score 0):

I have a mocked service which returns a simple function... [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d751ti?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) here... you can use the value as soon as the service returns a call

```
constructor(private uService: UploadService) {
    this.uploadMarketingAgreement('');
  }

  uploadFiles(event, type) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      this.uService.upload(this.formData).subscribe(
        response => { console.log("data from service:" + response); resolve(response); }
        , errr => { console.log("error from service:" + errr); reject(errr); }
      );
    });
  }

  async uploadMarketingAgreement(event) {
    const uploadFilesVal = await this.uploadFiles(event, "profilepic");
    console.log('from await:' + uploadFilesVal);
    //how to get result of the above method in a varaible
  }
```

Comment: in this method, my angular varaible not working , (this is becoming undefined)

Comment: if you share a stackblitz it'll be easier to help you through this